# Copy constructor of a doubly linked list (c++)

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, doubly-linked-list

I have been having trouble implementing a copy constructor for a doubly linked list. My professor provided a skeleton for a DLL class and i am implementing the functions as part of a project. Everything i have seen online has not proven to be too helpful because everything i see looks entirely different to the format of code i am supposed to be using.

For starters here's the DLL.h file

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    string ssn;
    string name;
    Node* succ;
    Node* pred;
};

class DLL{
    private:
        Node* headPtr;
        int itemCount;

    public:
        DLL();
        DLL(DLL& n); //Copy constructor
        virtual ~DLL();
        Node* getHeadPtr();
        int search(string ss) const;
        bool insert(string ss, string name, int & count);
        bool remove(string ss, int & count);
        int size();
        void display();
};
```

I have all the other functions implemented besides the destructor, which i haven't worked on yet but so far this is my code for the copy constructor:

```
DLL::DLL(DLL& n){
    n.headPtr = nullptr;
    n.itemCount = 0;

    Node* temp = headPtr;
    while(temp!= NULL){
        temp = temp->succ;
        insert(temp->ssn, temp->name, n.itemCount);
    }   
}
```

When i run this i keep getting segfault's. I have searched for some time on the internet but nothing similar enough to this format for me to comprehend has come up.

All help/suggestions/advice would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Edit: So now i have this, which works technically but a requirement is that the memory addresses are different. I was provided with a file test.cpp that runs the functions with example parameters and in the end the run is like Orig list: 12, 13, 14 (with memory adresses) followed by the new copied one.

Before i was getting segfault 11 but now it runs but is at the same memory addresses.

```
DLL::DLL(DLL& n){

Node* temp = n.headPtr;
headPtr = temp;
int count = 0;

while(temp != NULL){
    insert(temp->ssn, temp->name, count);
    temp = temp->succ;
}
```

}

Comment: That doesn't look like a copy operation to me.

Comment: Aside from mixing up your copy and move semantics, you null out the head node of the original list before you store the value anywhere. Also, it looks like you skip copying the first node.

Comment: *I have searched for some time on the internet* -- You have a bug.  The Internet is not going to debug your code.  You have to step through your code using a debugger to determine what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

first thing you do in your copy constructor is corrupting original list. `n` is list you are copying **from** and generally should not be modified, that is why usually copy constructors get `const Type&` as input argument.

you have to do something like

```
DLL::DLL(DLL& n) {
    int i = 0
    Node* temp = n.headPtr;
    while(temp != NULL){
        temp = temp->succ;
        insert(temp->ssn, temp->name, i++);
    }   
}
```

Comment: You know it completely went over my head that n is the list that i am copying from!!! That is a key factor to why i am screwing up i'd bet, thanks for that. I am gonna go tinker and see how i do.